# How to have different logos for different themes in magento 2.1

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a site that uses different themes for different categories.

I need to have a different logo for each theme, but in 'content > design > configuration' there is only the option to use a logo for a store front.
So the new uploaded logo is used across all themes.

Any ideas how I can use a specific image logo for each theme?

Comment: Create a system setting to Upload logo for different themes can you share the site link?

Comment: Site is in dev on my local machine, so not released to the masses yet.

I guess there is no native way to achieve this then.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following code to manage logo's to different theme's-

To declare a theme logo, add an extending `<theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` layout.

For example, if your logo file is my_logo.png sized 300x300px, you need to declare it as follows:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/my_logo.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Declaring the logo size is optional.

To learn more about theme layouts, refer to url : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html